# $(element).remove && append(element) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to preview files from my filesystem, the preview works on the first click, but it never updates after I click on different elements. I thought something might be wrong with my remove and append functions.
This is my JS code

```
function myFunction1(index) {
    var parent = $('embed#demo').parent();
    if (index == '0') {
        var newElement = " <div class = 'relative'> <embed
                src='http://localhost:8080//Part2/sample2.pdf' width='500' height='600'>
                </div>";
    }
    if (index == '1') {
        var newElement = " <div class = 'relative'> <embed
                src='http://localhost:8080//Part2/Capture.PNG' width='500' height='600'>
                </div>";
    }
    $('embed#demo').remove();
    parent.append(newElement);
}
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
```

and this is the html part:

```
<div class="panel-body" onclick="return myFunction1('0')">Panel Body</div>
<div class="panel-footer" onclick="return myFunction1('1')">Panel 
Footer</div>
```

This is the embed element
    `<embed id = "demo">`

Comment: Where is `#demo` element? Share the output of `console.log($('embed#demo').length)`, if it returns `0` means element doesn't exists. So neither `.remove()` nor `.append()` will work

Comment: Sorry i just edited that @Satpal

Comment: This is not the best approach because you're not displaying them dynamically.

Comment: Why are `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()` outside the event handler?

Comment: what should I do?? @HTTP

Comment: @AngelPolitis these were suggested by someone but what i used is inside the parentheses

Comment: Well, they are pointless. They are meant to be used **inside** the event handler to prevent bubbling and the default behaviour respectively, not outside. Also, `<embed>` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with this script that could be the cause:

- Event subscription with `onclick` attribute - use `$('.panel-body').click(...)` instead
- HTML attributes with `'`, like `<div class = 'relative'>` - HTML expects `"`, so use `'` around the string in JS
- `<embed>` tags are deprecated and may behave very differently depending on browser. For PDF just use `<iframe>`
- What do you expect `event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();` to do? This would stop the event with a direct subscription, but your `onclick` attributes are calling the function directly so they're never reached.
- The source is `http`, which will be blocked if your site is accessed over `https`.

Putting that together:

```js
function myFunction1(index) {
    var parent = $('#demo').parent();
    if (index == '0') {
        var newElement = `<div class ="relative"> <iframe
                src="https://localhost:8080//Part2/sample2.pdf" width=500 height=600>
                </div>`;
    }
    if (index == '1') {
        var newElement = `<div class ="relative"> <iframe
                src="https://localhost:8080//Part2/Capture.PNG" width=500 height=600>
                </div>`;
    }
    $('#demo').remove();
    parent.append(newElement);
}

$('.panel-body').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  myFunction1('0');
});

$('.panel-footer').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  myFunction1('1');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="panel-body">Panel Body</button>
<button class="panel-footer">Panel 
Footer</button>

This is the element <div id = "demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this

Answer (score -1):

Please try this one.

```
<div class="panel-body" onclick="return myFunction1('0')">Panel Body</div>
<div class="panel-footer" onclick="return myFunction1('1')">Panel Footer</div>
<div class="parent"><div id="demo"></div></div>
<script>
    function myFunction1(index) {
        var parent = $('#demo');
        if (index == '0') {
            var newElement = " <div class = 'relative'><h1>first</h1></div>";
        }
        if (index == '1') {
            var newElement = " <div class = 'relative'><h1>second</h1></div>";
        }
        $(parent).html('');
        parent.append(newElement);
    }
</script>
```